# Center Image on Card

Tags: javascript, html, css

Before you mark duplicate, I have read other posts on this topic, but my code is slightly different and I couldn't find one answering the way I did it.

```
            <div id="appB" class="containerB">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 order-first res-m-bttm-lg">
                            <card data-image="https://www.worldatlas.com/r/w728-h425-c728x425/upload/23/08/01/shutterstock-104644850.jpg">
                            <h1 slot="header">Spain</h1>
                            <p slot="content">Bet On Spain's Team playing against Portugal.</p>
                            <p slot="content">ETj9Qy3r5DyXw87qEHyp5gXhruFMuicEUR</p>
                            </card>
                        </div>
                  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.containerB {
padding: 40px 80px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Rest of CSS: [CSS Code (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/ZR9HTU07)

JS: [Javascript Code (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/8M9VhZwC)

Linking to a third-party site because the javascript was long and looked bad and would of been crowded.

This is how I set my card's background, but for some reason, it is off-center and for some reason it is showcasing some empty space.

[image: There is grey space and its blocking the image.]

If anyone can explain a solution, that would be very helpful.

Comment: assuming that you have a div or some container that have white border, you can use text-align:center or margin:0 auto in your css.

Comment: This did not work for me, I Updated the post with more code if it helps.

Comment: @BlakeXavier please include your CSS in the qustion...

Comment: Updated to show full code

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This did not work, I have updated post to add further code, it was working before, but when I added the cards into my site the images are off-center and hovering over them shoot out.

The code reflects what I want the cards to do, it'll make sense now hopefully.

Comment: You need to edit the card first, like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/feriagusetiawan/caxosdjh/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=caxosdjh)